# Why can I transmog X weapon into Y weapon but not Y weapon into X weapon?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I had a pickax and a sword on my Fury Warrior, and I wanted to have two pickaxes. But when I went to transmog it, I was unable to make my sword look like my pickax (counts as an ax). I assumed this was because the sword is a sword and the pickax is an ax. But, just to test it, I tried to transmog the pickax to look like the sword, and I was able to.

Why is it like this?

Both of them were two handed weapons and both were soulbound.

Comment: Some weapons (special items, fishing rods, anything lower than green,..) cannot be used for transmog. Try mogging another 2H axe with your pickaxe.. If that doesn't work the pickaxe is one of these unmoggable items. What pickaxe do you want to transmog?

Comment: @dly The pick weapon I am using is called the Cold Iron Pick, which is blue grade and a 2h ax, and the 2h sword was green grade. I did eventually get a 2h ax to circumvent the problem, but I want to know why I was able to make the ax look like the sword but not the sword look like the ax.

Comment: 2H swords, maces and axes can be transmogged into each others as long as you can equip them (and Warriors can), so it's probably something else... What sword do you use / try to transmog? Maybe I can reproduce the error when (or if) I have both weapons.

Comment: I was able to transmog my Warrior's artifact weapons (2H swords) and another 2H axe using the Cold Iron Pick, so it *does* work. We need more details about what you tried to do (character level, what sword, etc)

Comment: @dly The Transmog is a Merc Sword, so I belive it was a Merc Sword of the Tiger.  I was between level 12-18 at the time.

Comment: Ok, then your character's level was too low. The pick requires lvl 20 (or it did before they changed the whole thing), so you need to be lvl 20 to transmog it.

Comment: @dly I might have been a higher level then, because I had the pick equipped in my main 2-hand slot, with the sword in the second.

Comment: That might be a bug caused by the recent changes to the level scaling system in instances. You can enter the Stockade from lvl 15 to 60 and get the weapons according to your current level. My guess is that the system still thinks you're not yet supposed to have/equip it.. Just give it a try with a character above lvl 20 and see if that works. I just tried it with a lvl 60 Death Knight and it worked.

Comment: @dly that makes sense, as the new leveling system makes sure you can equip the items you get, right?

Comment: Yes, it works just like it already does in Legion and Timewalking instances. You can equip these items and they're scaled down/up to the level you have at that time (they don't grow with your level like heirlooms do). So getting a new axe 2 levels later will be better than the old one.

Answer (score 1):

From the WoW forums ["Transmogrification Rules"](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/3196342583).

I think the issue may be coming from

•   Main hand weapons can only be used to transmogrify Main hand weapons.

•   Off-hand weapons can only be used to transmogrify Off-hand weapons.

•   One handed weapons can be used to transmogrify a Main hand or Off-hand weapon.

Was it possible the other sword was an offhand weapon, so trying to transmog a pickaxe -> offhand didnt work?

Comment: Nope, 2H weapons cannot be main- or offhand items.